# Symfony backend: Load data on combo box depending on another

Tags: php, web-applications, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Im starting with symfony and im a little lost here. Of course nothing that a good tutorial can manage. However i've come to a point that my tutorial doesn't cover.

Creating the backend i write this generator.yml

```
...product/config/generator.yml
generator:
  class: sfDoctrineGenerator
  param:
    model_class:           Product
    theme:                 admin
    non_verbose_templates: true
    with_show:             false
    singular:              ~
    plural:                ~
    route_prefix:          product
    with_doctrine_route:   true
    actions_base_class:    sfActions

  config:
    actions: 
    fields:  
      product_type_id: {label: Product Type}
      product_name: {label: Product Name}
    list:    
      display: [product_type_id, category, product_name, created_at, updated_at]
    filter:  ~
    form:    ~
    edit:  ~        
    new:    
      display: [product_type_id, product_name, url, description, _category]
```

The last field is rendered throught a custom file _category.php

```
<?php 
    echo '<HTML CODE><select><option>...</option>';

    $query = Doctrine_Core::getTable('category')
         ->createQuery('c')
         ->where("id <> 1");
    $quer= $query->fetchArray();
    foreach($quer as $q) {
          echo '<option value="'.$q['id'].'">'.$q['category_name'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select> </HTML CODE>'
?>
```

It give a simple form to introduce the data, and its ok. But i was trying that the first combo box on the "new" action (product_type_id) allow me to modify the query of categories to display only those that match.

I wonder if i can access the value of product_type_id invoking some sfFuction or doctrine... or something.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: OMG why do you have a query in your view!?!

Comment: Did you try to do something by using AJAX?

Comment: You should use AJAX. A good starting point is this [blog post](http://nibsirahsieu.wordpress.com/2010/01/16/how-to-change-select-options-based-on-a-choice-made-from-another-select-using-ajax-in-symfony-1-2-or-higher/). It is for a frontend application but can be easily ported to an sf admin backend. Refactor your code and come back with problems that might occur

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Eventually i could do it with javascript.But AJAX will be my next subject :)